# When exactly do we start saying l'david for Elul?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, elul

Rosh Chodesh Elul is two days, and in Elul we say Psalm 27 in both morning and evening.  When exactly do we start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We started saying it tonight.

From [here](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/halacha.php?id=3281) (I added the bolding to the relevant part):

> Begin saying L'David Adonai ori v'yish'i (Psalm 27) on the first day (**at night**) of Elul, not the first day of Rosh Chodesh Elul (the 30th of Av).

Comment: We didn't say it tonight

Comment: What does the newest artscroll siddur say?

Comment: You gave a different answer [last time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18596/13438).

Comment: @Alex to a different question with different sources. This one presumes the 1st of Elul and asks night or day. The other asks about which day of Rosh Chodesh. The question was edited after I answered -- the original asked "When exactly do we start saying l’david tonight or tomorrow morningl'david for Elul?" and was posted Satuday night after the first day of R"Ch had ended.

Comment: But your answer here also addresses the other question (even if it wasn't asked here) and disagrees with your answer there. Namely, there you wrote that either day is fine (depending on minhag) but here you wrote that we specifically start on 1 Elul and not on the first day of Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @Alex this halacha clearly holds by one of those minhagim. The other question asked for which day so I reported 2 minhagim about which day. This one asked for the opinion that holds 1 Elul, night or morning so I gave the citation for "night." Gershon's answer gave another practice, also specifically geared for "1 Elul" not "either day depending on your minhag."

Answer (score 4):

Nusach Ashkenaz starts the night of 1 Elul as they say it at Maariv & Shacharis. Nusach Sefard starts the morning of 1 Elul as they say it at Shacharis & Mincha.

Comment: Unless they are following the original Nusach Ashkenaz without recent kabbalistic additions, in which case they'd never say it. Same for all other Nuachaot. (If you don't feel a need to say more things than your grandparents' grandparents did, this one isn't for you.)